# Replicate and permute in 4D

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, permutation, vectorization

Let `X1`, `X2`, `X3`, `X4` be row vectors of size `[1xN1]`, `[1xN2]`, `[1xN3]` and `[1xN4]` respectively. I would like to replicate and rotate these row vectors to obtain 4 corresponding 4D arrays `A1`, `A2`, `A3` and `A4` with size `[N1xN2xN3xN4]`. `X1` corresponds the `1st` dimension of `A1`, `X2` corresponds the `2nd` dimension of `A2`, `X3` corresponds the `3rd` dimension of `A3`, and `X4` corresponds the `4th` dimension of `A4`. For example, I can obtain `A1` and `A2` as follows

```
A1=repmat(X1',[1 N2 N3 N4]);
A2=repmat(X2,[N1 1 N3 N4]);
```

`A3` can be obtained with the following "amateur" code

```
A3Temp=repmat(X3,[N2 1 N1]); % [N2xN3xN1] array
A3TempRot=rot90_3D_2t(A3Temp,2,3,1,1); % Rotate 2 times to obtain [N1xN2xN3] array
A3=repmat(A3TempRot,[1 1 1 N3]);
```

For `A4`, I do not know how to do. After that, I would like to rotate these arrays to obtain `[N4xN2xN3xN1]` arrays. Do you have any idea about this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Tuan

Comment: Are you in essence looking for a 4D version of `meshgrid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you looked at `ndgrid`?

```
[A2 A1 A3 A4] = ndgrid(x2, x1, x3, x4);
```

Notice how `A1` and `A2` are ordered according to `x2` and `x1` due to the slight difference in functionality between `ndgrid` and `meshgrid`.

Comment: `meshgrid` only supports three input arguments.

Comment: Thank you all for your prompt reply. I completely forgot `ndgrid` function. It seems that `ndgrid` can answer for both "replicate" and "permute". In fact, to transform `X1`, `X2`, `X3`, `X4` into [N4xN1xN2xN3] arrays, we can use `[A4,A1,A2,A3]=ndgrid(X4,X1,X2,X3)`.